# Waiting on collection data prior to rendering a subview

Tags: javascript, model, ampersand.js

I am building what should be a fairly simple project which is heavily based on Ampersand's starter project (when you first run `ampersand`). My **Add** page has a `<select>` element that should to be populated with data from another collection. I have been comparing this view with the **Edit** page view because I think they are quite similar but I cannot figure it out.

The form subview has a `waitFor` attribute but I do not know what type of value it is expecting - I know it should be a string - **but what does that string represent?**

Below you can see that I am trying to fetch the `app.brandCollection` and set its value to `this.model`, **is this correct?** I will need to modify the output and pass through the data to an [ampersand-select-view](https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-select-view) element with the correct formatting; that is my next problem. **If anyone has suggestions for that I would also appreciate it.**

```
var PageView = require('./base');
var templates = require('../templates');
var ProjectForm = require('../forms/addProjectForm');


module.exports = PageView.extend({
    pageTitle: 'add project',
    template: templates.pages.projectAdd,

    initialize: function () {
        var self = this;
        app.brandCollection.fetch({
            success : function(collection, resp) {
                console.log('SUCCESS: resp', resp);
                self.brands = resp;
            },
            error: function(collection, resp) {
                console.log('ERROR: resp', resp, options);

            }
        });
    },

    subviews: {
        form: {
            container: 'form',
            waitFor: 'brands',

            prepareView: function (el) {    
                return new ProjectForm({
                    el: el,
                    submitCallback: function (data) {
                        app.projectCollection.create(data, {
                            wait: true,
                            success: function () {
                                app.navigate('/');
                                app.projectCollection.fetch();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is only the add page view but I think that is all that's needed.

Comment: FYI, some people have been helping me on the Ampersand.js Gitter chat. I will post an answer once I have figured it all out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The form subview has a waitFor attribute but I do not know what type of value it is expecting - I know it should be a string - but what does that string represent?

This string represents path in a current object with fixed `this` context. In your example you've `waitFor: 'brands'` which is nothing more than `PageView.brands` here, as `PageView` is `this` context. If you'd have `model.some.attribute`, then it'd mean that this string represents `PageView.model.some.attribute`. It's just convenient way to traverse through objects.

There's to few informations to answer your latter question. In what form you retrieve your data? What do you want to do with it later on?
It'd be much quicker if you could ping us on https://gitter.im/AmpersandJS/AmpersandJS :)

Comment: Thanks Kamil, as you can see in my comment above, I have had some help from some folks on the Gitter chat so I am nearly there.